# Repartition drives with GParted

Tags: centos, partition, gparted

Apologies for asking this question yesterday on a guest account that I lost access to. I've created and cloned a CentOS computer with a ton of customization. But when I originally set it up I had CentOS automatically configure partitions across my SSD and spinning drive. This resulted in the following filesystems and partitions that span both drives (lsblk output):

```
NAME            TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda             disk   
 sda1           part   /boot
 sda2           part
   centos-root  lvm    /
   centos-swap  lvm    [SWAP]
   centos-home  lvm    /home

sdb             disk
 sdb1           part
  centos-home   lvm    /home
```

I want to repartition it like the following below:

```
Partition FileSystem MountPoint 
/dev/sda1 ext4       /boot
/dev/sda2 ext4       /
/dev/sdb1 ext4       /storage
/dev/sdb2 ext4       /var
/dev/sdb3 swap       swap
```

How should I go about doing this? I tried using Gparted to repartition but afterwards I was unable to mount the partitions so when I rebooted it went to the grub-rescue menu. I am thinking that I can edit /etc/fstab to mount them and then I can do the repartitioning using fdisk, then reboot and it will work but I feel like I need a sense of direction instead of just trying things at this point.

Comment: Your repartitioning is probably going to involve reinstalling CentOS. If that's OK with you, do the install selecting "I will partition the disks" and set them up however you want.

Comment: @mpez0 I'd lose everything and have to do all my customization again from scratch which is what I'm hoping to avoid if possible. But if there's no other way then so be it.

Comment: do you have some media to which you could do a dump or other backup, and then a restore?

Comment: Sure. But How would you recommend I do the repartitioning?